# AspNetCore Identity Update DbContext At Runtime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, asp.net-core-identity

**Application:**

- .NET 5 Web API
- One sql database per customer
- JWT

**Problem:**

There is a controller called 'APIController' with the 'Authenticate' method.
This method is receiving the 'UserName' and 'Password' from the body.

With these parameters I am able to detect the customer's database but I don't know how to set the database (dbContext) into the userManager that I got through Dependency Injection.

```
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public APIController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserLoginModel model)
    {

        // Detect Customer's Database
        DbContext dbContext = GetCustomersDbContext(model.UserName);

        /* 
             Problem: 
             Check if the password is correct in the database I just found.
             How can I set the dbContext in _userManager?

             What I was trying to do:
             var store = new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(dbContext);
             var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(store,
                _userManager.Options,
                _userManager.PasswordHasher,
                _userManager.UserValidators,
                _userManager.PasswordValidators,
                _userManager.KeyNormalizer,
                _userManager.ErrorDescriber,
                _serviceProvider,
                _logger);
        */
    }
}
```

**Startup.cs**

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<FileWebDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
```

Many hours trying to find a solution, would appreciate if someone give me any idea!

---

Updated the solution [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66783532/3551489)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
public class APIController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
    private readonly IOptions<IdentityOptions> _identityOptions;
    private readonly IServiceProvider _serviceProvider;
    private readonly ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> _logger;

    public APIController(
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        IOptions<IdentityOptions> identityOptions,
        IServiceProvider serviceProvider,
        ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>> logger)
    {
        _userManager = userManager
        _identityOptions = identityOptions;
        _serviceProvider = serviceProvider;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> Authenticate([FromBody] UserLoginModel model)
    {

        // Detect Customer's Database
        DbContext dbContext = GetCustomersDbContext(model.UserName);

        // Solution
        UserStore<ApplicationUser> store = new(dbContext);
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> uManager = new(store,
                _identityOptions,
                _userManager.PasswordHasher,
                _userManager.UserValidators,
                _userManager.PasswordValidators,
                _userManager.KeyNormalizer,
                _userManager.ErrorDescriber,
                _serviceProvider,
                _logger);
    }
}
```